# Exposed filters not displayed in Drupal 7 - Views 7.x-3.0-rc1

Tags: drupal-views, drupal-7

in Drupal 7, using views 7.x-3.0-rc1 I can't see my exposed filters, they don't appear in any views type (block, page, attachement).

I'm new to Drupal 7 but have been using Drupal 6 for quite some time. is there something new with filters? is it a bug? Is anyone here experiencing the same problem?

Thanks

M.O

Answer (score 14):

I had this problem yesterday. The trick was to enable ajax for the display (that's how the preview works). After you do that, you should be able to see your exposed filters in the preview. See [this thread](http://drupal.org/node/1115782#comment-4384348) for further information.

In summary of that page, on the view page, go to `Advanced > Other > Use AJAX` and set it to `Yes`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too...I had to disable the theme developer. Somehow it was not displaying my filter.

Here it explains the issue..hope it helps [drupal](http://drupal.org/node/1107000)

Answer (score 0):

you can use better expose filter module in drupal 7 then enabled it then in expose filter filed chose better expose filter it shown u.